# Unpack object into optional parameters

Tags: node.js, redis-streams

I'll take Redis's `XADD` command as an example. I'm trying to allow my `write` function to write objects of varying lengths to the redis stream.

Originally, the command in `redis-cli` looks something like this:
`XADD streamName objectId key1 val1 key2 val2 ...`

And in NodeJS:

```
redisClient.xadd('streamName', 'objectId', 'key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

And I'm trying to wrap it in a simpler method:

```
write(object) {
  redisClient.xadd('streamName', 'objectId', <unpack object here>, function (err) {...});
}

write({key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', ...})
```

How can I unpack an object to function's optional parameters in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this I had to first turn the object into an array of its key-value pair and then unpack the array like so:

```
write(object) {
  message = objectToArray(obj); // in the OP example: ["key1", "val1", "key2", "val2"]
  redisClient.xadd('streamName', 'objectId', ...message, function (err) {...});
}
```